# Kubernetes cluster on AWS using kops without internet egress

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kops

**Goal**: To install a kubernetes cluster on AWS using kops without any internet access.

**Approach**: The `kops` tool generally has a lot of dependencies from the internet. The first and the most important one is `nodeup` which gets downloaded from s3. This `nodeup` binary needs some parameters to be passed in file `kube_env.yaml`.

```
Assets:
- 125993c220d1a9b5b60ad20a867a0e7cda63e64c@https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubelet
- 8e2314db816b9b4465c5f713c1152cb0603db15e@https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.8.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
- 1d9788b0f5420e1a219aad2cb8681823fc515e7c@https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/network-plugins/cni-0799f5732f2a11b329d9e3d51b9c8f2e3759f2ff.tar.gz
- f62360d3351bed837ae3ffcdee65e9d57511695a@https://kubeupv2.s3.amazonaws.com/kops/1.8.0/linux/amd64/utils.tar.gz
ClusterName: ${cluster_fqdn}
ConfigBase: s3://${config_base}
InstanceGroupName: ${instance_group}
Tags:
- _automatic_upgrades
- _aws
- _kubernetes_master
- _networking_cni
channels:
- s3://${config_base}/addons/bootstrap-channel.yaml
protokubeImage:
  hash: 1b972e92520b3cafd576893ae3daeafdd1bc9ffd
  name: protokube:1.8.0
  source: https://kubeupv2.s3.amazonaws.com/kops/1.8.0/images/protokube.tar.gz
```

As it can be seen in the above file, the packages and images are getting downloaded from the specified sources. It is fairly easy to customize the sources and point it to internal storage for all the packages that are mentioned in the file. But the `nodeup` and `protokube` seem to call the docker images from google's docker repository `gcr.io` which needs internet egress.

We tried to configure the manifests to point to a private docker repository hosted in the network where all the required images are stored. But the images to don't get pulled from the private repository and the cluster doesn't come up. This is the only blocker we are facing to achieve internet-free cluster. I'm assuming that the images are hard-coded inside the binaries. If that is the case, the only solution I can see is building a custom `nodeup` executable.

We are looking for other solutions or suggestions on the approach taken. Are the images hard-coded in the `nodeup` binary or is there some kind of a hash validation that happens? The `nodeup` source code is not well documented. So it is really difficult to pinpoint where exactly the images are being called.

Comment: _docker repository `gcr.io` which needs internet egress_ is only partially true -- if you are able to influence the machines to run `docker load` beforehand, then I would expect it would work without requiring Internet access; whether one can do that in `kops` is outside my expertise

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray/blob/master/roles/download/tasks/download_container.yml) has a dedicated step through which it knows to download all images onto a machine inside the VPC, and then distribute those images to machines that require them. I have fairly high confidence that I could kubespray a Vagrant cluster into service on an airplane